# Lookupset function in ssrs returning strange error

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to use the lookupset function in ssrs and I keep getting this error:

```
[rsLookupOfInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox46.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a lookup function with an expression that returned a data type that is not valid for the lookup function. The data type must be an RDL Variant type.
```

My first dataset looks like this:

```
Student Name      | PID
Anakin SkyWalker  | 1
Obi-Wan Kenobi    | 2
```

And my second dataset (named Awards) looks like this:

```
PID  | Xtrnl_Award_Type
2    | BA
```

The expression I'm using is:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!PID.Value, Fields!PID.Value, Fields!Xtrnl_Award_Type_Code, "Awards"), ",")
```

If the person doesn't have an entry in the second dataset, things are fine.  But if they do, my column just shows #Error instead a comma separated list of awards.  The field in question is a varchar, if that helps or not.  I don't understand why I'm getting an error or how I can see just what the expression is returning.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you missed a bit on the third parameter for the `LookupSet` function:

Instead of

```
=Join(
   LookupSet(
      Fields!PID.Value,
      Fields!PID.Value,
      Fields!Xtrnl_Award_Type_Code,
      "Awards"),
   ",")
```

Try this:

```
=Join(
   LookupSet(
      Fields!PID.Value,
      Fields!PID.Value,
      Fields!Xtrnl_Award_Type_Code.Value,
      "Awards"),
   ",")
```

(Actually, even then, the field name doesn't match what you show in your sample. You may need to change the parameter to `Fields!Xtrnl_Award_Type.Value`

Comment: Ye Gods, what a silly mistake.  I don't know how many times I looked at that darned expression and just did not see that missing bit.  Thanks!